# I want an image in background in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Help me putting an image in background instead of background color
I have tried Bootstrap's "img-responsive img-center" html tag but it doesn't appear behind text and CSS "background-image: url(");" not working at all

Here is CSS:

```css
header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #31353D;
}

header .container {
    padding-top: 74px;
    padding-bottom: 263px;
}

header .intro {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: 900;
     letter-spacing: 1px;  
}

header .subintro {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
}

Here is HTML
```

```html
<header>
 <div class="container"> 
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="intro-text">
     <span class="intro" id="mainIntro">We will lead the way</span></br>
     <span class="subintro" id="secondIntro">We provide not better but best in the world</span></br>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="introBtn">START YOUR JOURNEY</button>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

Comment: There is no image **anywhere** in your HTML or CSS.

Comment: I tried they are not working so i removed then posted there to ask proper solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `background-image: url()` and `background-size: cover` to header's css declarations after the `background-color` setting

([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/4wf7xg0g/1/))

```
header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #31353D;
    background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/1000/1000);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: i want background image instead of color

Comment: `background-image: url("../images/gentleMan.jpg");`
`background-size: cover;`

This worked for me, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

This should be simple

```
header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #31353D;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-g-640-480-8.jpg);
    /* or insert appropriate path to your image */
}
```

```css
header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #31353D;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-g-640-480-8.jpg);
    /* or insert appropriate path to your image */
}

header .container {
    padding-top: 74px;
    padding-bottom: 263px;
}

header .intro {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: 900;
     letter-spacing: 1px;  
}

header .subintro {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
}

Here is HTML
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
 <div class="container"> 
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="intro-text">
     <span class="intro" id="mainIntro">We will lead the way</span></br>
     <span class="subintro" id="secondIntro">We provide not better but best in the world</span></br>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="introBtn">START YOUR JOURNEY</button>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
```